# unable to see the output of printf statements or give inputs to scanf statements in the vscode terminal while debugging

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

when i try to debug my c code i can seee the variable changing their values in the debug section everything seems okay till here. but when i stepover to printf statements the statements are not executing in the terminal nor the scanf statements are executing. im unable to give inputs at run time while debugging my c code. in the image [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/joKa0.png).it is clear that even after executing that printf("heyy"); statement there is no output printed on the terminal. please help me resolve this problem.

i tried fixing it my own and took help from chatgpt, google ,youtube but i found nothing helpful:(

Comment: i'm able to get this print when running the same program:
hey
3,2,1,
Issue is not with the code.

Comment: environment issue, not code issue